# Kubernetes pull private external amazon ECR images

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ecs

I have an Amazon account with a K8S cluster which is able to pull images from the same account's ECR repository.

But, my company have another account with another ECR repository. How can I pull image from this "external" ECR repository ?

I'am also a Rancher user and I used to do this by installing a special container (https://github.com/rancher/rancher-ecr-credentials) which does the job.

Is there something equivalent for Kubernetes?

Thanks for your precious help

Comment: Have you thought of setting up node IAM roles in a way that would allow permit access to the registry in another account? If that's not something you can do, there must be some way of scripting creation of a secret that gets refreshed credentials when they expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have this setup for pulling images from the same account, you can do this with IAM policy level or ECR permissions, in your other AWS account set up a policy specifying the AWS account number (where k8s is) that will  be able to pull images

For example grant pull permissions in the ECR Permissions tab

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "k8s-aws-permissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_number:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think about it ^^